# How to create multiple progress bar in XML Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, progress-bar, android-custom-view

[image]

I have a **Recyclerview** which has **different row** items. One row item design is **poll result**. There are 2 to 8 poll results. So logically its not possible to create progressbar for each dialog in XML layout.

May I know how I can **logically create multiple progressbar with different color and percentage display**?

Comment: Have you tried setting a LinearLayout inside the dialog XML and then adding views(progressbar) to it?

Comment: @JimmyA.León No